# Inconveniente al ejecutar el RunServer en Python con el FrameWork desde Visual Studio

Tags: python, django

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles el favor con el siguiente requerimiento:
Estoy realizando un CRUD en Python siguiendo el siguiente video dentro de youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zNZ1lK6RTA&t=997s
todo funciona bien, hasta que en el tiempo 16:32 en donde uno va a activar el servidor con el comando python manage.py runserver
de la siguiente manera en la consola:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>python manage.py runserver
```

Me muestra estos errores:

```
Not Found: /
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2169
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2220
Not Found: /
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2169
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4181
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 21207
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/css/dark_mode.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2929
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2694
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3063
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 958
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/js/theme.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1943
[14/Sep/2023 09:42:48] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18533
Internal Server Error: /tasks/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\tasks\views.py", line 6, in list_tasks
    return render(request,'tasks/list_tasks.html')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: tasks/list_tasks.html
[14/Sep/2023 09:43:03] "GET /tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 500 80408
```

Agradezco anticipadamente colaboración

Comment: Buscaste el error que te aparece en el mensaje?. Por lo que se ve no encuentra un template y es el archivo list_tasks.html. Fijate en qué lugares de tu código lo estás mencionando y asegurate que el path esté correcto.